# Sum loop not performing addition.

Tags: arrays, loops, sum

I am unable to figure out why the numbers are not being added together. 
Everything else seems to work as intended.  Say, for example, I enter the numbers 3 and 4.  The sum is calculated as '034' and I need it to be '7'.

```
function calculateSumAverage(){
// get input
    var userChoice = document.getElementById("numInput").value;
// split it somehow with .split(" ")
    var array = userChoice.split(" ");
// set sum var to 0
    var sum = 0;
// set avg var to 0
    //var avg = 0;
// loop input array and sum
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
// calc average
    //var avg = sum / inputs.length;
// outpout to div
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum; 
    //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = avg;


}
```

Comment: I have two very simple questions... And I know I'll sound like a douche, but I will ask them anyways because, seeing this, I just have to... I. Just. HAVE. To! So here goes... First: What language is this in the first place? ಠ_ಠ --- Second: Regardless of language, did you SERIOUSLY need help to figure this out? ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)

Comment: The binary `+` operator is ambigious in JS. It can either be a numeric addition or a string concatenation. Your array contains strings, so JS won't do the math thing here.

Comment: @AlmightyR It's [tag:javascript]. The `document.getElementById(...).innerHTML` part makes that pretty clear/unambigious.

Comment: @Thomas Regarding javascript: I've been away from javascript for a long while now... Should have recognized it? Yes. Buuut, didn't. Meh ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ --- Also, as far as my experience goes, the `+` operator is implemented for strings (ambiguous with numeric types) in most languages... Any (possible but unlikely) confusion happening here is not due to the operator itself, but the language+implementation being loosely typed. Still, this should not be something one would not figure out on one's own; ever. Hahahahaha

Comment: I saw a video that showed a sum and average array that used the + in a way I also thought would just append a string but was able to generate a sum instead.  I didn't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would care to convert the array elements to integers prior to using `+` on them.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your output comes out as '034' is because `+=` on a string appends to the string. If your values inside the array are strings you need to parse them into integers before you can accumulate them.

A simple parsing can be achieved using `parseInt()`

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + parseInt(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried using parseInt earlier but I must have incorrectly used it.

Comment: @MatthewNeidig You're welcome. Small mistakes like this happen.